# Navigation bar alignment with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a header nav bar. This is what I have in HTML:

```
  <header>
       <nav>
           <ul>
               <li>Home</li>
               <li>About</li>
               <li>Contact</li>
               <li>Sign In</li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
  </header>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
header nav {
   text-align: right;
}

header nav ul li { 
   display: inline;
   font-family: Arial;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

While the `li` text is align to the right it is sitting on the baseline of the `nav` bar. What's wrong with the code? How can I improve the code? Thanks!

Comment: Your HTML appears to be missing a few opening `<ul>`s.

Comment: what do you expect it to look like?  So far, there is nothing wrong with the code. See http://jsfiddle.net/dRTHL/

Comment: yes its supposed to look like what you have there. on my page however it the text is sitting on the baseline and not in the middle. Also, I inserted a CSS reset before the code: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/. Does this matter?

Comment: The reset file has a definition for `li`s being on the baseline.  Perhaps you could include `!important` to your own if you cannot alter the order of CSS. Updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dRTHL/1/

Comment: Typically you want to add your CSS *after* the `reset.css`. Use `!important` if you cannot do that

Comment: For some strange reason !important didn't alter anything. I edited vertical-align in the CSS reset to reflect "middle" instead of "baseline" and it worked. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align` only works with things displayed as `table-cell`, which isn't widely supported yet (maybe I'm wrong here, been a while since I've checked). Also, I usually see the `li`'s of navigation floated left instead of displaying them inline. I'm not sure which is better, but I'm used to floating so that's what I'll use here.

What I usually do to "vertically center text" in navigation is add padding to the anchor elements. This gives you the added benefit of large clickable areas instead of just the text itself. **This will only work if your nav items are on one line**. If you need multiple lines then it gets much more complicated.

Here's some updated html, I've added the obligatory anchors:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="sign-in.html">Sign In</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

And the CSS can change quite a bit. This is the minimum to achieve the layout I think you expected.

```
header nav ul li { 
    float: left;
}

header nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

In this example I've centered the navigation text since that's what I *think* you wanted, but if not it can easily be changed back to `text-align: right;`.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9W2c2/)

[JSFiddle with the navigation floated right](http://jsfiddle.net/9W2c2/1/) thanks to [blurfus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600486/blurfus)

Comment: If OP is set on having Nav being on top-right, I updated fiddle like this http://jsfiddle.net/9W2c2/1/

Comment: yup this worked too. a quick question on html - is there a need to include <nav>? Or can I do away with it?

Comment: `<nav>` is another way to help define objects, so in this case you don't need it. You'll have to get rid of the `<nav>`s in your css though. That said, if you ever want to change stuff outside the `<ul>`, then you'd need a `<nav>`. Leaving it in will also give it more meaning when you or others read over the code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [@The Maniac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/528716/the-maniac) got your an answer.  You can also just update your **CSS** as below:

```
header nav {
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 10px; /* or whatever here */
}

header nav ul li { 
   display: inline;
   font-family: Arial;
   padding: 5px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the line height of li to work with vertical-align:middle